# How can I make following animation on iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uipageviewcontroller

I want to make animation on iOS like following links.
How can I make like this when scrolling?
Please give me some advice! thanks.

http://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/jian-danpurofiru-jiao-huan/id722084222?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rakunew/id725169455?mt=8

Comment: link 1,2 better u make a video of this and show it, link 3 u can achieve this by using page controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one looks like simple setFrame: animation on multiple views at once. To do it when scrolling, just interpolate between the start and end frame.

On second video, there's just changing frames and alpha blending (use view.layer.alpha for that). The dots in the bottom are, as Shan said, a UIPageControl.